# Octave vector multiplication inside matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

So I'm new to Octave / MATLAB, so you'll have to forgive me if this is a very simple question. Basically what I have is a nx1 vector and a mxn matrix, and I want to compute m dot products.

The operation I want to perform is this:

```
1     1,2,3     1+4+9       14
2  *  4,5,6  =  4+10+18  =  32
3     7,8,9     7+16+27     50
      1,2,3     1+4+9       14
```

Basically, I want to dot product my vector with every row of my matrix. Is there a simple Octave way to do this? Right now I'm trying something like: (with vector v and matrix m)

```
sum(v' .* m, 2)
```

Is there a better/faster way to do this?

Comment: `m*v`. I don't know if it's faster

Comment: Wow, I was really overcomplicating it haha. Thanks!

Comment: @LuisMendo It can be much faster indeed: about 10 times faster for `n = m = 1000` for instance (octave 3.8.2 compiled with serial gotoblas library on a nehalem cpu).